# Porting a multi-site setup to local (MAMP) server

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

There seems to be plenty of tutorials about setting up a local multi-site installation, however, I cannot seem to find any information about porting a live multi-site to a local environment.

Specifically I want to work on just one of the sites from the live setup. I am using Drupal 6. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. I have setup a database on my local MAMP server with the same name as one of the live sites that I want to work on.
2. I have imported the mysql dump of just the database I want (removing the others multisite sites from the dump).
3. All site files transfered to a folder in my MAMP>htdocs>new-folder-name
4. In new-folder-name>sites>desired-site-folder>settings.php I've set the db_url variable to `mysql://root:root@localhost/dbname`

What further steps do I need to take? When I navigate to the local site I get the  'It works!' message. I presume I maybe need to set up a htaccess file to redirect, but if so, how should it be formed?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've got MAMP pro, or have set it up as such (which you haven't mentioned) vhosts probably won't be enabled; Apache will be looking at MAMP > htdocs for the web root, not any folder underneath it.

Try moving the Drupal web root up one folder (i.e. directly under MAMP > htdocs) and try again

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't really want all the files directly in the htdocs folder, so I have since set up a vhost pointing to the new folder. I'm still getting the 'It works!' page, any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting the default Apache page then the web root you're browsing is still MAMP > htdocs (not the Drupal folder). Have you restarted Apache, added a relevant entry to /etc/hosts for the new vhost?

Comment: It's not the default apache page but the index.html page in the default Drupal set up, so the vhost is set up correctly. It seems to be from the index.html which needs some sort of redirection to use the appropriate site within the sites folder. I can't find where to tell drupal that I want a certain site's folder used from the sites folder.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean there - this is a purely Apache issue until you manage to connect to the Drupal website (The 'It works' page comes from Apache and Apache only). What happens if you visit http://domain/index.php directly?

Comment: Oh ok. When I visit domain/index.php the Drupal install process starts by asking me to chose a language to install Drupal in.

Comment: That's progress I guess...does Apache have read access to the sites/xxx.com/settings.php file? And just to rule out the blindingly obvious, your hosts file is definitely set up to forward http://xxx.com (the name of your sites/xxx.com folder) to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes the settings file has read access. I think your second question may be where the problem lies - how do I set up this forwarding?

Comment: Just add a line like `domain.com 127.0.0.1` to your `/etc/hosts` file, where `domain.com` is the name of the folder under `sites` where the site lives :) Quick way from terminal: `echo "domain.com 127.0.0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`

Comment: @tommyf Just my 2 cents, but if you're not running MAMP Pro, then get a license. It's seriously the best money you or your company will spend - and it's cheap compared to the headaches it prevents :)

Comment: Or just install XCode and use the local Apache/PHP configuration. It's pretty easy to set up; I've tamed it to use php 5.4 with pear/pecl and all the usual trimmings without much trouble

Comment: @Clive I'm still getting the 'It works!' page. My boss is sorting MAMP Pro for me today hopefully it will work with that, I'll let you know

Comment: @Clive I've got Mamp Pro now but still having problems. I have added a new host - 'mysite', disk location is pointing to the root of the Drupal install (not the folder inside 'sites'). The folder inside sites dir - 'site.newsite' contain the multisite I want to work on. When I visit http://site.newsite.mysite I'm getting 'cannot find server'. Mamp pro also has an option for 'alias' do I need to set anything here?